# Gaussian elimination and solving linear system in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

So I'm supposed to create a function that inputs a matrix A and right hand side vector b. It should perform gaussian elimination and outputs the solution x of Ax=b. Here is what I have so far, some of which was provided in class.

```
function [x] = myLU(A,b)
%Gaussian elimination first
for i=1:n-1
%ith step
    for k=i+1:n
    %kth row
        multiplier = A(k,i)/A(i,i);
        for j=i+1:n
            A(k,j)=A(k,j)-multiplier*A(i,j)
        end

        for j=i+1:n
            b(j)=b(j)-multiplier*b(i);
        end
    end
end
%upper triangular
for i=n:-1:1
    %solve for x(i), assume x(i+1)...x(n) are known
    x(i)=b(i);
    for k=i+1:n
        x(i)=x(i)-A(i,k)*x(k);
    end
    x(i)=x(i)/A(i,i);
end
```

The issue is that it's returning NaN for each value in the vector x. I also noticed that when returning the matrix A in the middle of the function, it is not returning an upper triangular matrix. Also, it is telling me that n is an undefined variable, but I'm not sure how to define it other than assigning it a specific number. Am I missing an entire piece of the function or is my coding off somewhere?

Comment: Gaussian elimination and LU decomposition are two different things.  Lower/upper triangular suggests LU to me.

Comment: @duffymo A canonical way to compute the upper triangular matrix in a LU decomposition is to perform Gaussian elimination.

Comment: You are most likely having one of the diagonal coefficients in the matrix `A` being set to 0. When performing row operations, the multiplier will thus be infinite. This infinite coefficient thus distributes over all rows after. Also, you have some implementation errors, such as calculating what the new right-hand-side coefficient vector values are.  Your code is very similar to the duplicate I've marked. Please see it to correct your code.